# Rest best practices: what standard should I follow?

Tags: rest, spring-rest

I read following books and links before I post this question and since this question is about best practices, this question might be closed. However i am expecting some expert views.

https://www.restapitutorial.com/resources.html
REST-API-Design-Rulebook book from oreily
other blogpost and stackoverflow question.

For example to get information about employee with id we are using `uri` as below

```
http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/employees/employeeid/123456
```

But all above resources tell me to do this way

```
http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/employees/123456
```

Similarly if i want go get information about employee with id 12345, my uri is as below

```
http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/countries/country/US/employeeid/12345
```

as opposed to

```
http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/countries/US/12345
```

Does that mean my uri are not standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just guidelines. You can't cover all kinds of possibilities of your business and necessities on a Rest documentation.

Talking about your examples, the

> `http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/employees/employeeid/123456`

And

> `http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/employees/123456`

Are both correct. But could be better (shorter).

Usually I prefer the second one and use the first one for the **alternatives**. Per example, if I would like to find an employee by id (the "default" method to find employees) or his unique internal company code, I prefer to use respectively:

```
/employees/123456         # by id
/employees/code/A899123A  # by code
```

> Similarly if i want go get information about employee with id 12345,
>   my uri is as below
>   http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/countries/country/US/employeeid/12345

This URL means to me that you trying to find an employee with id 12345 on the US country. But could be shorter too if the `US` term is the default method to find countries on your API:

```
 /countries/US/employees/12345
```

> as opposed to http://myapp-name.myorganization.com/countries/US/12345

This one seems confuse. Are you trying to find what with id 12345? It's hard to answer only looking for the URL. So, the `/countries/US/employees/12345` is more consistent.

If the idea is find the employee on some country with some code, the URL can follow the same pattern: `/countries/US/employees/code/A899123A`

Answer (score 2):

> Does that my uri are not standard?

No, your URI are fine.  REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your identifiers, so long as they are consistent with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).  There's also [RFC 7320](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7320), which describes "Best Practices" -- but you will probably find that those best practices still leave you with a lot of freedom.

Think "variable names" - various communities will have their own conventions for how variable names should be spelled, but there isn't any standard.

The same holds for identifiers in REST -- they are opaque strings that neither the API consumer nor the client actually need to parse.  (Example: when's the last time you actually looked at the URI used when you submit a search to Google?)

Some routing frameworks will be easier to use if you adhere to a particular convention, but that's purely an implementation detail on the server, the client doesn't care.